# No signal with DiplayPort

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have an i5 Lenovo m91p pc ([this is the spec](https://support.lenovo.com/il/he/documents/migr-76747))

win 10 pro 64 bit.

I have a little problem with my DP port.

I purchased a DP to HDMI adapter to connect my pc to tv.

last week when I first used it, every thing was great. I used my tv as a second monitor.

but today, when I tried to connect my tv I got a "no-signal" all the time.

I tried every thing- including updating drivers and enable in bios - but nothing!

I have no idea what to do.

Last week it worked just fine, and today it doesn't recognize the DP at all! only the vga works.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a different HDMI port on the TV?

Comment: yes.
I also tried other HDMI cable. both hdmi cables checked on my streamer and they worked well.